# Excel VBA Copy Paste error

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets of same data

```
A  B  C
   5  6
4  3  3
```

**Formula 1**

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim Current As Worksheet


  Range("A2").Copy _
  Destination:=Range("A1")
  Range("A2").ClearContents         

End Sub
```

The formula works for me. But I need to apply this script to all sheets,

**Formula 2**

```
Dim Current As Worksheet

         ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
         For Each Current In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Current



           Range("A2").Copy _ Destination:=Range("A1")
  Range("A2").ClearContents
            End With
         Next Current


End Sub
```

--> It works but values in A1 also deleted. And it is not being used for all sheets. Only active sheets.

Comment: FYI.. they are not formula

Answer (score 3):

A [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) can carry a parent worksheet reference along in a block of commands but you must prefix each `.Range` or `.Cells` reference with a period (aka *full stop*) to accept the parent worksheet relationship.

```
Dim Current As Worksheet

' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
For Each Current In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Current
       .Range("A2").Copy Destination:=.Range("A1")
       .Range("A2").ClearContents
    End With
Next Current
```

Note `.Range` and not `Range`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works  like a charm. Thank you so much. Great help